# AWK with one decimal place

Tags: awk

My current script is giving output with many decimal places. Is there any way to get only 1 place in the output?

```
# cat sample
HDD Used: 15.0223T
HDD Total: 55.9520T

# cat sample | awk ' /HDD Total/ { hdd_total=$NF }
      /HDD Used/ { hdd_used=$NF }
      END {
        used=hdd_total-hdd_used
        print "cal =" used}'
```

**Current Output**

```
cal =40.9297
```

**Required output**
    `cal =40.9`   **---> With only one decimal**

Getting error for this

```
# isi storagepool list -v| grep -i 'HDD Total:' | awk '{print "HDD Total=%.1f", $NF -1 " TB" }'
HDD Total=%.1f 54.952 TB
#cat isistorage1 
7.332T     n/a (R)   13.01% (T)

# cat isistorage1 |  awk '{ print "Snapshot USED=", $1}'
Snapshot USED= 7.332T
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `printf "cal =%.1f\n", used` instead since it has print type modifier control and area.

The `.1f` there means, only print 1 decimal place after a floating point, you can change it to any number you want in decimal places.

Comment: this is not working for this `awk '{ printf "Snapshot USED=%.1f\n" $1}'`

Comment: added the error to the question.

Comment: what value the `$1` has taken in your `awk` command? it's a floating point value? what this command `tail -n -1 |` gives in output in your command?

Comment: @Shanker: `$1` should be an argument to `printf` add a comma and it should work

Comment: i tried the same but still unable to do so.

Comment: @shanker make sure you're using `printf`, not `print`

Answer (score 3):

You can tell awk which floating-point conversion to use by setting `CONVFMT`, the default is `%.6g`, e.g.:

```
cat sample | awk -v CONVFMT='%.1f' '
/HDD Total/ { hdd_total = $NF }
/HDD Used/  { hdd_used  = $NF }
END {
  used=hdd_total-hdd_used
  print "cal = " used
}'
```

Output:

```
cal = 40.9
```