# Setting Input field to 2 decimal points (Price)

Tags: bash, floating-point

I am currently trying to input prices into a .txt file.

So i want it when the user input:`1.1`

Instead of `1.1`, I want it to become `1.10` instead. As it would look better for the table I am trying to make in the future. I would also like to round up or down if it goes more than 3 decimal places. (*Thanks john1024 for the correction*)

Comment: Oh... Alright i'll edit my question. Thanks!

Comment: So... `read x; printf '%.2f\n' "$x"` maybe? See `help printf` and `man 3 printf`

Comment: umm. But i don't want it to just print 2 decimal places. I want it to store the additional 0 at the back. Similarly for the other decimal places.

Comment: To store the additional zero in variable `x2`: `read x; printf -v x2 '%.02f' "$x"`

Comment: Wow... Sorry for asking such a stupid question. Thanks!

Comment: @John1024, that sounds like an answer to me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AWK with one decimal place](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/383378/awk-with-one-decimal-place)

Comment: See also [How can I add (subtract, etc...) numbers with bash?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/93029/80216)

Answer (score 1):

To read in a price and coerce it to have 2 decimal places, try:

```
IFS= read -rp "Enter the price: " var
printf -v var %.2f "$var"
```

The `%.2f` format tells `printf` to use two-decimal digits.

Examples:

```
$ IFS= read -rp "Enter the price: " var; printf -v var %.2f "$var"; echo "var=$var"
Enter the price: 1.2
var=1.20
$ IFS= read -rp "Enter the price: " var; printf -v var %.2f "$var"; echo "var=$var"
Enter the price: 1.123
var=1.12
```

**Note:** Bash's `printf` builtin can format numbers with decimal points but its arithmetic expressions cannot handle floating point numbers.  For that, you will need more advanced shells such as ksh93, zsh or yash or tools like `awk` or `bc`.